# What is the significance of the manna?

Tags: mon-manna, test, observance

In the Torah, Moses tells the Israelites:

> [Remember God] Who fed you in the wilderness with manna... that He might humble you, and that He might test you, to benefit you in the end.  [Deut. 8:16]

We heard that earlier [Ex. 16:4].  Rashi says the test was whether the Israelites would follow the directions about gathering manna: First, not storing any of it for the next day, and second, collecting a double portion before Shabbat, but none on Shabbat.  Sforno says that the test is: Will the Jews still follow the Torah when they do not have to worry about their livelihood?  The Ramban says the opposite: God wanted to force them to live from day to day, to see if they would keep their faith even under conditions of uncertainty about the next day.

But if the manna “test” is really whether we would still be observant when our needs are met (or are uncertain), one would expect the phrase “to test you” to be repeated every time God gave us something: Water in the desert, freedom from slavery, a guide to the Promised Land, victory in battle, etc.  But it is not repeated.  So why does only the “manna” constitute a “test”?

Comment: In the other cases you mention when we got something, it was a constant. Only Manna was something that was given each day anew. People would be worried that it won’t come again tomorrow since it was so supernatural. If for example, there were freed and then forced back into slavery each evening and redeemed again each morning, it would be similar.

Comment: The water, the victories were not one-time things.